# Same NullReferenceException but with different messages. what's the reason?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

`NullReferenceException: A null value was found where an object instance was required`

I want to know what conditions cause these two different messages to occur.

Comment: Post the code that results in these exceptions.

Comment: Even though you have two different messages, its the same error, you have a variable that is not referencing anything on the heap, therefore it is null, so when you try to access a property of that object for example you have this exception since it is not set to anything

Comment: The 2nd is what you get if someone tries to avoid the 1st. However usually the 2nd case should be a Argument Exception.

Comment: @preciousbetine Sorry. Only have stacktrace.

Comment: The answer in short: Different libraries throwing the exception. The first one is the`c#` default message the second a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a [Exception from the Framework itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception).

The second one, is someone trying to avoid the first case by throwing a custom Exception. However I think he messed up a bit: Usually you should be using a ArgumentException for this case, not a NullReference one. Exactly because it causes this kind of confusion.

Edit: As Gabriel Luci pointed out, this might come from working with Unity3D. Unity spend years being developed against the Mono Framework for Platform Independant Development (Platform Indepedance only materialized for .NET around .NET Core). So they might have followed a different pattern/set of Localisation Strings.

For Exception handling (catching, throwing your own and rethrowing), I have two [Articles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) [I link often](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET). Those are what I base my "I think he messed up" on.

Comment: The second one is thrown by Unity. At least, when you [search for that message](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+null+value+was+found+where+an+object+instance+was+required), all the results are about Unity.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: Then it must be their mono heritage.The only reason I can think why this would have two Exception Messages.